# javascript to replace text on hard coded webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hard coded webpage that I can add parts containing scripts. I need to add a script to change the word Attendees to Count throughout the page and the pages with in it. 
This is the code wrote and have been playing with but its not functioning.

```
<p> </p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("Attendees", "g"), "Count");
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: take a look at the js replace documentation, you are doing it wrong: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: Your script tag is in inside the body. It could well be executing before the body has been rendered and therefore the regex won't find anything.

Comment: It seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j4mUH/. Please provide more information. Could it be that some content is loaded via Ajax?

Comment: As @DanIveson pointed out, if this is in the body, then it will run as soon as it's parsed, and the elements might not be loaded yet.  If you place it at the end, just before `</body>`, then it might work.  I don't see any issues with the actual JS (aside cleaning up the regex declaration by changing it to `/Attendees/g`)

Comment: w3schools is not a good resource for referencing documentation.  MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) is much better, and probably easier than the actually W3C spec. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.body.innerHTML = 
        document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Attendees/g, "Count");
}
</script>
```

You need to make sure your script runs after the page has completely loaded: `window.onload`\

Also check out the `replace` documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: If the `<script>` tag is placed at the end of the `<body>`, then this won't make a difference.

Comment: Thank you!This works on the first page only and will not run through the other layered pages. I need to run it through all layered pages.

Comment: Any thoughts on getting it to run through layered pages?

Comment: It sounds you are asking a new question. What exactly do you mean by layered pages?

Comment: This is on a hard coded registration page so there are layered pages through the registration process. I need to do the same replacement throughout these layers, but each layered page does not its own coding. Sorry if this isn't clear, this old hard coded website is the death of me and I can't wait until we change.

Comment: I think you need to start a new question (making sure to accept this answer as correct first). I am still unclear what you mean by layered pages? If you can control the code on one page why not the others?